# Processing TensorFlow Records that are XML (text)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to use TensorFlow to process XML strings that are proper TFRecords.  I'm curious to understand how to structure code that parses each TFRecord.  There is a set of input rules and data type mappings that are applied to each TFRecord record to produce an output TFRecord.

Example input TFRecord:

```
<PLANT><COMMON>Shooting Star</COMMON><BOTANICAL>Dodecatheon</BOTANICAL><ZONE>Annual</ZONE><LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT><PRICE>$8.60</PRICE><EXTREF><REF1><ID>608</ID><TYPE>LOOKUP</TYPE><REF2><ID>703</ID><TYPE>STD</TYPE></EXTREF><AVAILABILITY>051399</AVAILABILITY></PLANT>
```

The rules show what needs to be parsed and how it needs to be formatted.  E.g. find the COMMON, PRICE, EXTREF>REF2>ID and AVAILABILITY elements and export their values as a TFRecord.

Example output TFRecord:

```
Shooting Star,8.60,703,51399
```

How do I add this logic to a graph so when it executes it produces the output TFRecord?  My initial thoughts are that I need to translate the mapping logic into a series of tf.ops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md) will be very helpful to you. It specifies the exact format that the `TFRecord` needs, and it provides the code to turn your own dataset into a `TFRecord` file.

However, that link did not mention `XML` files. It only talked about how to create a `tf_example` and turn it into a `TFRecord`. This [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py) will actually go a step back and show you how to turn a `XML` file into a `tf_example`. Note that it will need some modification to fit your needs because it is using the Oxford Pet Dataset.

Comment: Both links are unavailable now.